# Right of way for a raised crossing?

Tags: legal, uk, etiquette, london

The new Cycle Superhighway 3 goes through Hyde Park, London,UK on West Carriage Drive.

It contains a number of points at which pedestrians are evidently intended to cross, as the roadway and cycleway is raised.

Unfortunately, this is the best picture I have of one which was taken while CS3 was under construction: the raised segment of the crossing continues into the cycle lane.

[image]

However, I have noticed on my commutes that very few cyclists or pedestrians seem to know who has the priority at these crossings. They are not laid out like zebra crossings, as exist on some cycle lanes in london, which had led me to believe that the cyclists had priority, and the raised sections were advisory in nature to pedestrians, just like crossing islands are usually when not marked by a zebra crossing.

The highway code seems to me to be silent on the issue: it only mentions specific types of marked crossings, rather than generic raised crossings with no markings.

Who has the priority here?

As requested by one of the comments, this is what one of these looks like:

[image]

[image]
Both from West Carriage Drive in Hyde Park
https://maps.app.goo.gl/L3J2urZCehHJj1Uj8

Comment: This looks like London; I've added the corresponding tags. There is more than one Hyde Park in the world (London, Chicago, Boston, Sydney, etc.)

Comment: I would expect that the posted traffic control tells everyone what to do.  So if there's a red light, you stop.   If there's no controls or signs, then users travelling along the road have priority over those crossing the road (the type of vehicle is irrelevant.)

Comment: In the US, pedestrians have the right-of-way at marked crosswalks.

Comment: In some jurisdictions within the US, pedestrians even have the right-of-way at *unmarked* crosswalks, at any intersection (and only at intersections, not just anywhere).

Comment: @ScottHillson - Yeah, most stated have that rule, but there's a lot of fine print that wouldn't summarize well.  And it's a rule greatly ignored by motorists (even more than with marked crosswalks).

Comment: So this cycleway is named as a "superhighway" ?  From the name alone I'd be astonished if the cyclists have to give way to anything for the length of the "superhighway" part.   @private101 can you please keep this question updated as construction progresses?

Comment: @Criggie Only one of the "superhighways" is anything like that. [Mostly it's cycle lanes painted blue.](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2016/aug/07/london-cycle-superhighways-heaven-or-hell)

Comment: @criggie the picture's an old one and the cycle lane has been in use a while. It's a two-lane cycle path kept separate from the roadway. There are standard traffic controls on it, but there are a few unmarked crossings on this stretch.

Comment: @ASimmons then they're not prioritised crossings in the English sense, because they are unmarked.   If anyone can find or take an updated photo of this crossing for the question, that'd be good.

Comment: It looks like they have tried to copy a Dutch style raised crossing, where the slow traffic crossing would have the right of way. But in those the road surface of the crossing is that of the side walk or cycle path. In this case it is the road surface of the road, so I would say it is a widened speed bump and not a crossing. As slow traffic I would give way to road traffic in this situation. (But I am not completely familiar with the local laws and traditions in the UK.)

Answer (score 6):

The vehicular and cycle traffic has priority, since the crossing is not a zebra crossing and there are no traffic lights, which are the only situations in which the Highway Code talks about pedestrians having priority.

However, as you have noted, many people seem to be confused by the crossing, so you should be ready to stop in case a pedestrian does step into the roadway or cycle lane. Also, be alert to the possibility of motorists stopping and beckoning pedestrians to cross into your path and the possibility of a group of pedestrians blocking the cycle path because it was clear when they started to cross but now they're waiting for cars on the road.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Traffic Signs Regulations and General Directions 2016 (TSRGD) and Highway Code pedestrians only have priority at zebra and parallel crossings (which include stripes flashing orange Belisha beacons, single dashed give way markings and zig-zags) and when crossing a side road at a junction, and at a crossing of a cycle track marked with zebra stripes or just double dashed give way lines against the cycles or at traffic signal controlled crossings and junctions with pedestrian lights.

The situation in the photo is an informal courtesy crossing with illegal and misleading signage. The Traffic Signs Regulations and General Directions (which must be adhered to on publicly accessible roads in the UK) states that the triangle sign used is only to warn of zebra and parallel crossings. The Traffic Signs Manual indicates it should be placed some distance in advance of the crossing, not at it. Therefore you could reasonably interpret it to mean that you needed to give way 20m or 50m down the road at a zebra-type crossing. The text on the plate beneath the sign is not in the TSRGD so is illegal unless it has approval from the Secretary of State for Transport. If at a formal controlled crossing on a raised table it should say 'Humped crossing'. In the event of a collision the Highway Code, TSRGD and TM can be easy to argue that the incorrect signage is dangerously confusing.

The correct signage in advance of the courtesy crossing would be an '!' warning sign with 'Pedestrians crossing' beneath e.g. https://images.app.goo.gl/VriHygDAECDWyvgJ9 and also have a hump warning sign (or 'Traffic calmed area' sign) if the road is not in a 20mph zone.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer, with detail and correct use of references.

Answer (score 1):

English law is actually very clear. It is deemed to be who is at fault. Pedestrians are very rarely at fault (a resent case of a pedestiran crossing a road whilst looking at her mobile phone only partially relieved the cyclist of fault.) Even if there is no crossing at all, a pedestrian will rarely be found at fault under English Law.

In this instance both motorists and cyclists are clearly being warned of a pedestrian crossing. You will also find a warning triangle some distance ahead of the crossing. There are again triangles in front of the raised crossing. Therefore if a cyclist or motorist hits the pedestian, then 99.9% of the time the cyclist or the motorist will be deemed at fault. Furthermore, if the pedestiran if injured or killed this could result in a criminal conviction against the cyclist or motorist.

Therefore act diligently and give way to the pedestrian.

Comment: Welcome to the site, it would be useful to have some references to back up the statements if you wanted to [edit] that in

Comment: Without references, this answer is pure conjecture and/or opinion.

Answer (score -1):

The highway code simply makes little-to-no reference to this specific situation. There does appear to be a somewhat similar raised crossing in the image below rule 206:

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/road-users-requiring-extra-care-204-to-225

[image: code 206]

In this image the cars have the yield triangle signifying the give-way. This seems to suggest, albeit not in writing, that the pedestrians have priority. That fits with the overall theme of the code that pedestrians have the priority at designated crossings that aren't signal controlled.

Comment: Is the "yield triangle" you reference the hazard marking white paint on the ramps? That strikes me as subtle for a legal instruction, and also likely not present on the cycleway the OP was asking about.

Comment: @Móż - In the OP's image you will notice that there's a traffic sign at the crossing.  I can't make it out completely, but one word appears to be "Pedestrian".

Comment: @DanielRHicks you mean the one on the other side of the road? Admittedly, while it's under construction there's no way to know, but in Melbun(Oz) we have similar paths with crazy mixtures of actual pedestrian crossings both across and "along" the bike path (it's not legal to ride on the ones along the route), raised sections with and without give way signs, sections where markings disappear, and places where pedestrians are encouraged to walk across or along the marked bike path. So I'd be looking for clarity, not guessing based on loosely adjacent signs.

Comment: Those white triangles are NOT yield triangles- they are speed table markers to alert road users to the fact that the road has a raised section. These are totally independent of pedestrian crossings or having to yield.

In the linked section of the highway code, the image above is used as an example of an area where one should "drive carefully and slowly". This suggests to me that there is no obligation to stop, and that road users have priority.

Additionally, having cycled that route myself, the sign says "raised pedestrian crossing" but is only visible to car users from 1 direction

Comment: There is no "overall theme... that pedestrians have the priority at designated crossings that aren't signal controlled." Pedestrians who are on zebra crossings have priority; pedestrians on signal controlled crossings have priority when the signals give it to them. In all other situations, the traffic has priority (though, of course, if there is a pedestrian in the road, you must avoid hitting them, regardless of whether or not they were supposed to be there).

Comment: @ASimmons In particular, yield triangles are long and hollow, and the point of the triangle faces the oncoming traffic. These are short and solid and the point points away.

Comment: @DanielRHicks The sign says "Raised Pedestrian Crossing", so I think you are right. I do not think that sign would be put there just for the construction period, so it must be intended as a permanent pedestrian crossing.

Comment: @jcbrou not all places pedestrians are intended to cross give them priority. An example can be found [here](https://www.trafficchoices.co.uk/images/schemes/refuge_island.jpg) which is an identical situation to the pictured one without the raised section.

Comment: @ASimmons Good point, I didn't think about that. Now that brings to mind another issue: Will the pedestrians think of that?

Comment: Theyre the wrong way up for *give way* triangles ("yield" isn't used in this sense in the UK).  They're also exactly the same markings as used on other speed bumps, including ones that don't have a flat top from one kerb to the other.  Raised *crossings* are marked as crossings (zebra stripes)

Comment: @jcbrou the sign is on the road not the cycle path.

Comment: Another point is that, if that speed table was actually a pedestrian crossing, parking would be prohibited close to it, or the pavement (sidewalk) would intrude into the road so that pedestrians could see around the parked cars.

Comment: @ChrisH Good point.